# sequelize returns null for column 'id' in the dataValues of a query result.

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am using the sequelize in combination with my nodejs typescript application and am facing the following issue. I created a class called OrmMapper which is responsible for creating my tables. I created a table called "PCS" and initialized it with the following code:

```
    PCS.init({
      id: {
        primaryKey : true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      owner : DataTypes.INTEGER,
      created: DataTypes.DATE,
      year : DataTypes.STRING
    }, {sequelize});
```

The generated DDL is fine and the problem occurs whenever I run this piece of code:

```
handleGetByOwner(request: TrackerRequest, res:Response):void{
  this.pcsModel.findAll({where:{owner: request.queryParams.ownerId}}).then((dataPackage:any)=>{
  let PCSS = [];
  console.log(dataPackage);
  for(let pcs of dataPackage){
    PCSS.push(pcs.dataValues);
  }
  res.status(200).send(new TrackerResponse({success: true, payload: PCSS, timeStamp: new Date()}));
});
}
```

which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT `id`, `owner`, `created`, `year`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `PCs` AS `PCS` WHERE `PCS`.`owner` = '1';
```

When I look in my database, all the data inserted is correct, when i execute the above SQL statement everything works. However when I run the server code above the result of my query is:

[image: queryresult]

All of the datavalues are correct, expect for id which is null.